# add mime type for js file

Tags: 7, theming

I want to add mime type for js file 'youtube.js' which helps to pause and play the youtube video.I have included in info file as `scripts[] = js/YoutubeVideo.js`.
I caught the error

> The resource from “http://test.com/themes/sample/js/youtubeVideo.js?oqctd7” was blocked due to MIME type mismatch (X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff).

I have inspected the source file this file is included as `<script type="text/javascript" src="http://test.com/themes/sample/js/youtubeVideo.js?oqctd7"></script>`

I want to change the mime type application/javasccript.How can I do it

Answer (score 0):

You can make you own tag with [drupal_add_html_head](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21common.inc/function/drupal_add_html_head/7.x.)

Something like this: (not tested )

```
$element = array(
  '#tag' => 'script', // The #tag is the html tag - 
  '#attributes' => array( // Set up an array of attributes inside the tag
    'href' => 'http://test.com/themes/sample/js/youtubeVideo.js?oqctd7', 
    'type' => 'application/javasccript',
  ),
);
drupal_add_html_head($element, 'youtube_video');
```

Put this code in the YOUR_THEME_NAME_preprocess_html function.